# Using MathBox2 and A-Frame together

Tags: aframe

MathBox is great math visualization tool created on top of Three.js and [ShaderGraph.js](https://github.com/unconed/shadergraph). I'm currently working on explorable explanations for college math and want to use both A-Frame and MathBox in single project (A-Frame driving webVR stuff, scenes, events, physics, roomscale for HTC Vive and MathBox for 2D/3D math visualizations, animations).

I've asked about this in MathBox's google group here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mathbox/FwCxKeNQ0-g

Steve Wittens (creator of MathBox) answered:

"A-Frame and MathBox are both based on three.js so the compatibility is possible in theory, but nobody has made the necessary bindings. You'd probably want to look at the examples/test/context.html example to help you figure out how to connect on the MathBox side."

Code from `examples/test/context.html` that he mentions:

```
var WIDTH = 640;
var HEIGHT = 480;

// Vanilla Three.js
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, WIDTH / HEIGHT, .01, 1000);

// Insert into document
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

// MathBox context
var context = new MathBox.Context(renderer, scene, camera).init();
var mathbox = context.api;

// Set size
renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
context.resize({ viewWidth: WIDTH, viewHeight: HEIGHT });

// Place camera and set background
camera.position.set(0, 0, 3);
renderer.setClearColor(new THREE.Color(0xFFFFFF), 1.0);

// MathBox elements
view = mathbox
.set({
  focus: 3,
})
.cartesian({
  range: [[-2, 2], [-1, 1], [-1, 1]],
  scale: [2, 1, 1],
});

// Initialize grid (something similar like aframe-gridhelper-component)
view.grid({
  divideX: 30,
  width: 1,
  opacity: 0.5,
  zBias: -5,
});

// Animated Math.sin() function
view.interval({
  id: 'sampler',
  width: 64,
  expr: function (emit, x, i, t) {
    y = Math.sin(x + t) * .7;
    emit(x, y);
  },
  channels: 2,
});
```

How should I connect a MathBox and A-Frame?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a mathbox [system](https://aframe.io/docs/0.3.0/core/systems.html)?

```
AFRAME.registerSystem('mathbox', {
  init: function () {
    var sceneEl = this.el;
    if (!sceneEl.renderStarted) {
      return sceneEl.addEventListener('renderstart', this.init.bind(this));
    }

    this.context = new MathBox.Context(sceneEl.renderer, sceneEl.object3D, sceneEl.camera).init();
    this.mathbox = this.context.api;

    // MathBox elements
    this.view = mathbox
      .set({
        focus: 3,
       })
      .cartesian({
        range: [[-2, 2], [-1, 1], [-1, 1]],
        scale: [2, 1, 1],
      });
    };
  }
});
```

And then you can write components that talk to mathbox.

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('mathbox-grid', {
  init: function () {
    var view = this.el.sceneEl.systems.mathbox.view;
    view.grid({
      divideX: 30,
      width: 1,
      opacity: 0.5,
      zBias: -5,
    });
  }
});
```

And then just:

```
<a-scene> 
  <a-entity mathbox-grid></a-entity>
</a-scene>
```

Though you will probably need to bind a lot more stuff like positioning, rotation, scale? You can also prefab it:

```
AFRAME.registerPrimitive('a-mb-grid', {
  defaultComponents: {'mathbox-grid': {}}
});

<a-mb-grid></a-mb-grid>
```

### Alternative / Quick Path

if you don't want the declarative goodness, let A-Frame create the scene/renderer/camera, and use the three.js object3Ds directly in combination with mathbox. Here is [documentation about scene and how to access its object3Ds](https://aframe.io/docs/0.3.0/core/scene.html)

Comment: When I register a new `mathbox` system, I get error: `three.js:8786 THREE.Object3D.add: object not an instance of THREE.Object3D.` and it throws when I call `init()` function from `this.context`. When I googled around, I found out that this error happens when different versions of Three.js are loaded. `mathbox-bundle.js` comes with Three.js r71 and A-Frame is using Three.js r76, so I took only `mathbox-core.js` (without Three.js bundled) and error disappeared. Now there's some breaking changes between those two Three.js versions, seems like I would need to rewrite MathBox core to support it.